# Как реализованы роли для объектов в ролевой модели?

Tags: windows, теория

Какие есть роли для объектов? Как они реализуются? (конкретно интересует реализация в системе Windows)

В классической ролевой модели нет понятия ролей для объекта. Информации о ролях или группировках тоже не найти.

Не подскажете какие-нибудь книги по этой теме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Роли объектов реализуются через группировку объектов. А группировка объектов реализуется в Windows NT, к примеру, через наследование. Дочерние файлы в родительской папке наследуют спецификаторы доступа родителя. Конечно, можно и выборочно настроить параметры наследования.